# How to input integer values in a list(python 3.x)?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

I am trying to use list as an array and I want to enter integer values in the list so that I can perform some arithmetic on it.

```
m=int(input())
```

I always used this for getting some integer input from the user.

```
//creating an array

myArray=[]
inp=int(input("Please enter the length of array you wish to create"))
for m in range(inp):
    myArray.append(int(input()))
print(myArray)
```

But this isn't working. Why?

> Error :invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: What does the user type?

Comment: In Python 3.5.1, I get an error that includes the string that failed, e.g. for the empty string (because I entered nothing): `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` Are you not seeing those final quotes with the literal it tried to parse?

Comment: @zondo integer data that he wishes to add in the array

Comment: @brainst I mean what is his example that results in that?  If he types the right numbers, he shouldn't get an error.  I tested it, and it works if the right numbers are typed.

Comment: @zondo it seems that you're right

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a terrible mistake :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## REPL Demo

Okay, since the input would be parsed as a string and `int` can only coerce strings that are just numbers into integers... you are in big trouble for a bad input as it would stop your program immediately.

I would suggest using a `while` loop and `try-except` exception statements for error handling.

***NOTE for Python 2.x***: Use `raw_input` since `input` would result in a `NameError: name <input_string> is not defined` if you pass characters without string quotations.

```
>>> my_array = []  # camelCase is not the convention in Python
>>> 
>>> array_length = None
>>> while array_length is None:
...     try:
...         array_length = int(input("Please enter the length of array you wish to create: "))
...     except ValueError:
...         print("Invalid input - please enter a finite number for the array length.")
... 
Please enter the length of array you wish to create: 4
>>>
>>> print(array_length)
4
>>> while len(my_array) < array_length:
...     try:
...         my_array.append(int(input()))
...     except ValueError:
...         print("Invalid input - please enter a number!")
...
1
abc
Invalid input - please enter a number!
2
3
4
>>>
>>> print(my_array)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

## Running as Script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

INVALID_NUMERIC_INPUT_MSG = "Invalid input - please enter a finite number with no spaces!"
KEYBOARD_INTERRUPTION_MSG = "Keyboard interruption: program exited."

def main():
    my_array = []

    print()

    array_length = None  
    while array_length is None:  # accept input until valid
        try:
            array_length = int(input("Please enter the length of array you wish to create: "))
        except ValueError:
            print(INVALID_NUMERIC_INPUT_MSG)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\n" + KEYBOARD_INTERRUPTION_MSG)
            quit()

    print("Your array length is {}.".format(array_length))
    print()

    while len(my_array) < array_length:
        try:
            my_array.append(int(input()))
        except ValueError:
            print(INVALID_NUMERIC_INPUT_MSG)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\n" + KEYBOARD_INTERRUPTION_MSG)
            quit()

    assert len(my_array) == array_length  # check for program correctness

    print()
    print("Your array is: {}".format(my_array))
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running in my console:

```
$ python3 input-program.py

Please enter the length of array you wish to create: 4
Your array length is 4.

1
2
3
4

Your array is [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: there's a syntax error :/ `print my_array` `print(my_array)` is also giving me a syntax error? What is the actual syntax? I tried searching but didn't get it

Comment: Hm, I fixed a couple things since I wrote this in Python 2.x and just realized they deprecated `raw_input` in Python 3.x, but everything else still works. Does the `SyntaxError` point at the first parenthesis in `print(my_array)`? If so, it's most likely an indentation error in the console.

Comment: Actually .. There's something strange .. I wrote the program then I run in IDLE then it says syntax error. But If i directly run in IDLE then it doesnt

Comment: @brainst: Hmm, I don't know what's the problem. I wrote the script and ran it in the REPL/IDLE and it works flawlessly for me. Let me know if there are any problems remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The str to int coercion can be done by just trying it out, to see if it input was a number.

Here we make a zeroed array and a consecutively numbered array (a range)

In python you call an array a list

```
array = [0]
try:
    array = array * int(raw_input('How long? ->'))
    print array
except:
    print "try using a number"
```

OR

```
try:
    array = range(int(raw_input('How long? ->')))
    print array
except:
    print "try using a number"
```

PS this is Python v2 code not v3